# How to organize the variable and methods definitions when developing universal application for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, preprocessor, ios-universal-app

I m looking for a preprocessor or something like that that will help me to define variables or methods depending on the device type iPhone or iPad.
I found something related here : [Preprocessor-IF doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027168/preprocessor-if-doesnt-work) - where it is advised to use

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
    #define IS_IPAD false
#endif

#define WIDTH (IS_IPAD ? 768 : 320)
#define HEIGHT (IS_IPAD ? 1024 : 480)
```

but suppose I have variables defined in the interface that are to be used separately based on device

```
Class1 *object1; //specific for iPhone
Class2 *object2; //specific for iPad
```

Or methods that are used depending on device, how do I differentiate?

Comment: When you use the recommended way advised by the link you provided, your code should know if it is a iPad or an iPhone. So why can't you use a if..else block or something similar to create your variable/methods? I am not sure what you mean with your question...

Comment: But I cannot add if else in interface. Even if I add as #if, Because of the reason Preprocessor rules are processed prior to building the app-desired behavior is not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many as objects in any class, the main thing is at which time you are allocating those classes, you will be writing the code, calling the methods, depending on the device.

So this doesn't make any sense, you can have both objects in the class, & declare in the header file. And in the `dealloc` check before calling `release` to those objects.

Comment: I want the code to be obvious for understanding. I can use comments or pragmas but it is not the way I want. Something like a preprocessor where anyone can see and identify the code's running platform. Not sure but I guess some load will be off if I have class methods that are not required so not loaded and same with instance variables reference pointers. But my main purpose is code readability.